# rating bar not showing all five stars with wrap content and also custom style not working android

Tags: android

i am trying to show rating for items in recyclerview list.by which user can see and give their feedback. i have tried with custom rated star color and empty star color.but its not working well.the problems are,all five stars not showing there(4 star showing). and i wanted to customize star's selected and empty color but thats also not working.
here is my adapter code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:id="@+id/productImageViewId_deal"
        android:src="@drawable/wad_logo_sparkle"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/productTitleTvId_deal"
        android:text="£25,500 FORD GALAXY TITANIUM "
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#0e4f71"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productImageViewId_deal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/productDescTvId_deal"
        android:text="2.0 5DR HEATED FRONT SEATS, ACTIVE PAR"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productImageViewId_deal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/productTitleTvId_deal"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/productLocTvId_deal"
        android:text=" Ilford, 0, England"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/location_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#777"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productImageViewId_deal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/productDescTvId_deal"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/productPostTimeTvId_deal"
        android:text="May 06, 2016, 12:1914"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productImageViewId_deal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/productLocTvId_deal"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="£25,000.00"
        android:id="@+id/productPriceTvId_deal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#1470a6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productImageViewId_deal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/productPostTimeTvId_deal"
        />

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productImageViewId_deal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/productPriceTvId_deal"
        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is style:

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

        <item name="colorControlNormal">#1470A6</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">#c44</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tested lot's of ways and no good result at the end.
You can use
`style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Indicator"`
or use some libraries like MaterialRatingBar.